# Python: line appending at the end instead of Replace in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, str-replace

I'm new to python,
Actually I'm writing Python script to replace specific line in a file but line appending at the end instead of Replace in a file.

Below is snap of my code please look on -

Assuming file1 and file2 are different,

```
d = file2.readline()
z = file1.readline()

if d in z:
    print("Match_Found")
    file2.write(z.replace(d, ""))
```

Above code will not replace the specific string of the line,

Can any one help me out thanks

Comment: if a line in file d is available in file z then you want to make that line empty right ?

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: same question. but in my case, I want to replace the same file. any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to read from a file, and write in another (new) one.

Read your input file line by line. If the line does not "match", just write it as is in your output file. If it "matches", write the replacement string in the output file.

If you really want to replace the file (not creating a new one), you can delete your input file and rename your output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
import io

with open('sample1.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines1 = list(f)


with open('sample2.txt', 'r') as f1:
   lines2 = list(f1)

count = len(lines1)
counter = 0

for k in range(0, count):
   if lines2[counter] == lines1[counter]:
      with open('sample2.txt', 'a') as f3:
          print("Match found!")
          f3.write('\n' + lines1[counter])

 counter += 1
```

You want to open the file that you want to write to in append mode, and you want to use the new line character in order to start a new line. 'a' for append mode.

Comment: If file1 and file2 are diffrent? then this solution will not works rt?